# Migrating user names with accent causes integrity constraint violation

Tags: users, migrations

I'm migrating users from a Drupal 6 to a Drupal 8 site. I use the original d6_user source plugin provided by the User module, so nothing really specific about that part.

I'm experiencing many integrity constraint violation errors with messages similar to the following.

> 1062 Duplicate entry 'Saïd-fr' for key 'user__name' trying to insert datas in users_field_data table. user__name is a unique key composed of name and langcode field.

Investigating a bit more, I found the original Drupal 6 site user data had another name entry of value "Said" for the same language (since both sites are monolingual). Checking users table definition shows the collation is utf8mb4_general_ci. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332387/mysql-unique-index-doesnt-work-on-a-certain-umlaut) the ci suffix means *case insensitive*, which means for example I, i or even ï are considered the same by MySQL when comparing strings, which  leads to the duplicate entry error. For the record, the Drupal 6 users table from which the name field comes from has the latin1_general_ci collation. Although it is 'ci' suffixed, it obviously authorizes this kind of duplicate.

This lack of compatibility between Drupal 6 and Drupal 8 database schema is for me a problem, since I'm unable to migrate approximately 800 user accounts. I've changed this specific field to utf8_bin collation and it seems to correct the issue.

Do you think it's a good solution? Is the utf8_bin the best collation for that purpose? Can it lead to problem in the future to change the Drupal 8 database schema?